# Best_in_place tab trough

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I'm using best_in_place gem so I can edit multiple students in my index view.

The problem though, is that the usuability is bad.
I have to click, type the info, enter/click and click again to edit another information.

Is that a way that I can press Tab to go trough the fields?

Here is the code of the Index:

```
<% @students.each do |student| %>
   <tr>
   <td><%= link_to .name, edit_student_path(student) %></td>
   <td><%= best_in_place student, :oral %></td>
   <td><%= best_in_place student, :writing %></td>
   <td><%= best_in_place student, :participation %></td>
   <td><%= best_in_place student, :grammar %></td>
   <td><%= best_in_place student, :presence, type: :select, collection: [["Present", "Present"], ["Absent", "Absent"], ["", "-"]] %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

I found this: https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/tree/master/lib/best_in_place

Ok.
This is what I get now, But still's not working :/
Any Ideas?

index:

```
 <td><%= best_in_place allan, :oral, :html_attrs => {:tabindex => 10} %></td>
 <td><%= best_in_place allan, :writing, :html_attrs => {:tabindex => 11} %></td>
```

Users.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
$('.best_in_place').best_in_place()

$ ->
  $('span.best_in_place').focus ->
   el = $(this)
   el.click()
   el.find(el.data('type')).attr('tabindex', el.attr('tabindex'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can hack around a little bit using `tabindex` HTML attribute and `focus` event like this:

```
   <td><%= best_in_place student, :oral, :html_attrs => {:tabindex => 10} %></td>
   <td><%= best_in_place student, :writing, :html_attrs => {:tabindex => 11} %></td>
   <td><%= best_in_place student, :participation, :html_attrs => {:tabindex => 12} %></td>
   <td><%= best_in_place student, :grammar, :html_attrs => {:tabindex => 13} %></td>
   <td><%= best_in_place student, :presence, type: :select, collection: [["Present", "Present"], ["Absent", "Absent"], ["", "-"]], :html_attrs => {:tabindex => 14} %></td>
```

and this JS

```
$(function() {
  $('span.best_in_place[data-html-attrs]').each(function() {
    var attrs, el;
    el = $(this);
    attrs = el.data('html-attrs');
    if (attrs && attrs['tabindex']) {
      el.attr('tabindex', attrs['tabindex']);
    }
  }).focus(function() {
    var el;
    el = $(this);
    el.click();
  });
});
```

That last line of the JS code is searching for the element type of BIP form and assigns the `tabindex` so the order of tabbing is maintained.

**UPDATE**: The CoffeeScript version of the above JS

```
$ ->
  $('span.best_in_place[data-html-attrs]').each ->
    el = $(this)
    attrs = el.data('html-attrs')
    el.attr('tabindex', attrs['tabindex']) if attrs and attrs['tabindex']
  .focus ->
    el = $(this)
    el.click()
```

Comment: Is there a especific place to put the js code?
I put it in the users.js. but now I'm getting an error.

Comment: `SyntaxError: reserved word "function" on line 7
  (in C:/Users/SpeedUp/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/participatio/app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee).`**
Line 7 is your JS conde. :/**

Comment: The JS code wasn't intended for CoffeeScript, I updated the answer with the CoffeeScript version.

Comment: I don't get the error now. But is not workin still. :/
I updated my code.

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong, please check the answer again. And you don't have to stick to `tabindex` starting from 10 BTW.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fugure that the numbers are telling the sequence to the browser. It first edit the oral of all posts to go back to writing of the first one. So I changed all the numbers so they are the same. And it works on sequence now. Thanks alot.

Comment: This is excellent. If you're editing in place on a table of many records you can use 'each_with_index' to increment your tab indexes.

Comment: It should be noted that `html_attrs` currently does not work. When using that it creates a data tag `data-html-attrs`.

Answer (score 1):

BIP changed their naming structure. They also included some tabindex support.

Via gem github:

> HTML Options:
>
> If you provide an option that is not explicitly a best_in_place option
> it will be passed through when creating the best_in_place span.
>
> So, for instance, if you want to add an HTML tab index to the
> best_in_place span just add it to your method call:
>
> `<%= best_in_place @user, :name, tabindex: "1" %>`

However, I did not get this to work out of the box (or at all). I ended up altering Ahmad's JS solution above to comply with the new naming structure. It works pretty well though tabbing through `:select` fields continues to be a problem.

```
$(function() {
  $('span.best_in_place[data-bip-html-attrs]').each(function() {
    var attrs, el;
    el = $(this);
    attrs = el.data('bip-html-attrs');
    if (attrs && attrs['tabindex']) {
      el.attr('tabindex', attrs['tabindex']);
    }
  }).focus(function() {
    var el;
    el = $(this);
    el.click();
  });
});
```

JS is not my strong suit. If anyone has any suggestions for tabbing through `:select` dropdowns please reply! Thx

Comment: I needed to use your code with Ahmed's html. That worked.